# Differences in mounting components in unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, jestjs, enzyme

So I've seen multiple approaches to rendering components for unit tests over the time, the testing framework in question is not relevant..
I'm wandering **is there any advantages or disadvantages to any of the following approaches?**

for example, is there any chance of memory leaks in any of the following approaches?

1st approach, using a shared variable between all tests and mounting before each. (main problem I can think of overriding the default component props can be tricky)

```
describe('some describe', () => {
    let component
    const baseProps = {}

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = shallow(<MyComponent {...baseProps} />)
    })

    it('test 1', () => {
        expect(component).to.something
    })

    it('test 2', () => {
        expect(component).to.something
    })
})
```

2nd approach, calling renderComponent in the beginning of each test but still using a shared variable

```
describe('some describe', () => {
    let component;

    function renderComponent(props = {}) {
        const baseProps = {}
        component = shallow(<MyComponent {...baseProps} {...props} />)
    }

    it('test 1', () => {
        const props = {}
        renderComponent(props)
        expect(component).to.something
    })

    it('test 2', () => {
        renderComponent()
        expect(component).to.something.else
    })
})
```

3rd approach, mounting the component in each test

```
describe('some describe', () => {
    const baseProps = {}

    it('test 1', () => {
        const props = {}
        const component = shallow(<MyComponent {...baseProps} {...props} />)
        expect(component).to.something
    })

    it('test 2', () => {
        const props = {}
        const component = shallow(<MyComponent {...baseProps} {...props} />)
        expect(component).to.something.else
    })
})
```

4th approach, using a helper function that returns an instance for the test

```
describe('some describe', () => {
    function renderComponent(props = {}) {
        const baseProps = {}
        return shallow(<MyComponent {...baseProps} {...props} />)
    }

    it('test 1', () => {
        const component = renderComponent()
        expect(component).to.something
    })

    it('test 2', () => {
        const component = renderComponent()
        expect(component).to.something.else
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - `component` is created in `beforeEach` so it can't be customized by the test before it is created (as you noted).

2 - `renderComponent` works through side-effects...best practice is to avoid them.

3 - works fine

4 - works fine...preferable to 2 since `renderComponent` is a pure function.

---

All four behave similarly since `Jest`, `Mocha`, and `Jasmine` all run `beforeEach` hooks before any tests in the same `describe` and run tests in the order they are defined.

All four only use variables local to the `describe` callback (and in 4 everything is even more localized to the test callback) so as long as your component cleans up after itself (example: clear any timers, global listeners, etc. in `componentWillUnmount` and call `unmount` on your component) none of the four are more prone than the others to memory leaks.